# Find number of integers satisfying $x^{y^z} \times y^{z^x} \times z^{x^y}=5xyz$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, diophantine-equations

Find number of integers satisfying $$x^{y^z} \times y^{z^x} \times z^{x^y}=5xyz$$

My try:

we can rewrite the equation as

$$x^{y^z-1} \times y^{z^x-1} \times z^{x^y-1}=5$$

Then since all are integers we get

$x=5$, $y=1$ ,$z=1$ and like wise we get other two triplets.

is there a way to do formally?

Comment: You should also consider triples with one of the coordinates equal to $0$, I think. $(0,1,1)$, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Finding all of the solutions may be tricky, but counting how many there are is very easy!  Notice that if one variable is $0$ and the other variables are positive, then both sides are obviously equal to $0$.  So this gives infinitely many different solutions, since the other two variables can be any positive integers.  (More precisely, there are $\aleph_0$ solutions.)

Answer (score 1):

The factor of $5$ must come from somewhere, so $x, y$ or $z$ must have a factor of $5$ (let's just assume it's $x$, as the expression is symmetric). The power of $x$, i.e. $y^z - 1$, must be strictly positive. If there were any other prime factor of $x$, because $x$ is raised to a positive integer power, it would have to divide $5$, hence $5$ is the only prime factor of $x$. Moreover, we can similarly see that $25$ does not divide $x$, so $x$ is $5$ (or $y$ or $z$, when you account for symmetry).

Since $x = 5$, we must have $y^z - 1 = 1$. We already knew it had to be strictly larger than $0$, but if it were at least $2$, then $25$ would divide the left side but not the right side. Thus we have $y^z = 2$.

Similarly, this means $y = 2$. We know via the same arguments that $2$ must divide $y$, that $2$ is the only prime factor of $y$, and if $y$ were a power of $2$ greater than $2$ itself, then $y^z$ would be divisible by $4$. Similarly, $z = 1$.

So, our only possible solutions are $(x, y, z) = (5, 2, 1), (2, 1, 5), (1, 5, 2)$, by symmetry. Are they solutions?

**No**. There are no solutions.

Comment: This is correct assuming all variables are positive, but there is no such assumption in the problem.

Comment: I was actually just going from the working the asker provided. I get the impression that $x, y, z$ are meant to be positive anyway, from the wording of the question and from the working already done.